# Remove delay before loadingMessage appears in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

On my tablet, there is delay of between .75 and 1.5 seconds between the time a page link button is pressed and the time the jquery-mobile default "loadingMessage" (just a transparent black box that says "loading") appears.  I would like to make it appear instantly.

To clarify, the current process is like this:

```
finger touches button ---- ~1s delay ---> "loading" appears ---- 1-2s ----> new page finishes loading via ajax and slides into view
```

I would like it to be:

```
finger touches button ---- 0s delay ---> "loading" appears ---- 2-3s ----> new page finishes loading via ajax and slides into view
```

In case it's relavant, the code for my link button looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-block-a"><a href="/Buynow" data-role="button" class="name-button">Alan Jones</a></div>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Have you looked at [fastclick](http://labs.ft.com/2011/08/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/)?

Comment: @Jack Pretty sure what I'm seeing is not the 300ms delay described in that article.  It's a) longer than that and b) you can tell the click event registers ~1s before the "loading" overlay pops up, because the button changes color almost instantly after the tap

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do. My application is exactly the same. The button registers the click instantly, but the page transition still takes a good 1-2 seconds to kick in.

Comment: @Jeemusu, Is there a way to manually invoke the loadingMessage to come up?  That way, you could attach it to the onclick event handler directly.  Feasible?

Comment: You can call it programmatically: `$.mobile.loading( 'show');` or i think you can even add the `show-page-loading-msg` class to the button